# Divisors of Prime Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me with this?

Consider a positive natural number of the form $n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_m^{a_m}$ where $p_1,\dots ,p_m$ are unique prime numbers and $a_1, \dots ,a_m \in \mathbb{N}$

How many divisors does $n$ have of the form $q^k$ where $q$ is a prime number and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is a positive integer?

I just know that the number of divisors of $n$ alone is $(a_1+1)\dots (a_m+1)$. But I am confused when the divisor has a form. Is it $(a_1+1)\dots (a_i-k+1)\dots(a_m+1)$ if $p_i=q$ for some $i$.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: $q^2$ and $q^3$ , where $q$ is prime, are considered the same case?

Comment: Try answering the question for $n=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5$, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin I followed your example and I concluded that the number of divisors is just the sum of the exponents. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q^k$ is a divisor of $n$ then $q=p_i$ for some $i$ and $k\leq a_i$. So the answer is $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_m$.